# Prove partials are equal to the determinant given some properties.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

i have to prove that:
Given $x:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},x(r,\theta)=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},y(r,\theta)=r\sin(\theta)$. Prove that 
$$
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}(r_0,\theta_0)=\mbox{Determinant of }Df(r_0,\theta_0)=r_0
$$
I demonstrated that the determinant evaluated in $(r_0,\theta_0)$ is equal to $r_0$. But im confused with the partials, because i have only worked with partials of the style $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ so i don't know how even start, any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial derivative notation
$$
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}
$$
is used to represent the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) (in particular see [example 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation)):

$$
\displaystyle \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The notation is also sometimes given as (as can be seen in the Wikipedia article): $\frac{d \mathbf{v}}{d\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\partial \langle v_1,v_2 \rangle}{\partial \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle}$.